# number of views for each list item

Tags: 2016, count

I have a list for announcement, I need to count the number of views for each item!

How can show the total number for each item view in the display form? is it possible without coding!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot do that out of the box. What you could do is to create a javascript solution to handle it.

The way I would do it is to create a list - lets call it viewcount - to keep the data about views with two fields: IdOfViewedItem and ViewCount

Write a script and place it on the display form of the item you want to track views on. The script should check if an item exists in the list viewcount, if not create it and set view count to 1. If the item exsits get the current viewcount and add one to the count.

Now this isn't by any account a bullitproof solution, especially if you have several hundred users accessing the item at the same time (The script would fire massively and updating the item will not be able to keep up most likely).

Comment: I am newbi, please help me with a script to start

Comment: It's not really something you 'just do' if you have no experiece in the area. In that case I would suggest either finding some in your organisation who know a bit about javascript or comission somebody to write it for you. I will not be ableto/have the time to help you to the extend you would need at this point.